# Is there any SDK compatible with C# to get live data from a network fingerprint reader like EP300?

Tags: c#, network-protocols, fingerprint

Is there any SDK compatible with C#  to get live data from a network fingerprint reader like EP300?

I made an app on C#/SQL Server only compatible with usb fingerprint readers (with Griaule SDK), but now i need made it compatible with network fingerprint readers, getting the live data from the machine

I  just found this, but it's incomplete

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/125530/FingerPrint-machine.aspx

Comment: i just found two SDK to work with network devices.

Just as i told you i have an ANVIZ EP300, but still couldn´t make it work with this SDK because is it in Visual Basic (old) and i work with C# 2010.

Just in case here is ANVIZ SDK

http://www.microcom.com.ar/anviz/sdk.rar

If someone can translate it to C# and make it work, i would be very happy :D

And i found Suprema Products SDK too, but i do not have a Suprema Device to test it

http://www.fingerprint-it.com/Downloader.aspx?dir=Downloads/SDKs&file=BioStar%201.26%20SDK.zip

Answer (score 3):

Yes, download the C# sdk version from the following [link](http://www.files.com/set/5205aeeb584ce)

Comment: thanks, i am checking it but gives me some errors, could you know why?

Comment: BTW, try to put the tc400.dll files in your system32 directory

Comment: Does you have any project done with this SDK? @mleger45

Comment: Yes, I have, in fact I changed it from VB to C#